# Ariflow [Errno 104] Connection reset by peer

Tags: python, rabbitmq, celery, airflow, airflow-scheduler

I am trying to run tasks through the command 'airflow scheduler' when it produced this error, AFTER I tried to run one of the dags.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/usr/local/bin/airflow", line 28, in <module>
args.func(args)
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/airflow/bin/cli.py", line 839, in scheduler
job.run()
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/airflow/jobs.py", line 200, in run
self._execute()
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/airflow/jobs.py", line 1309, in _execute
self._execute_helper(processor_manager)
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/airflow/jobs.py", line 1441, in _execute_helper
self.executor.heartbeat()
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/airflow/executors/base_executor.py", line 132, in heartbeat
self.sync()
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/airflow/executors/celery_executor.py", line 88, in sync
state = async.state
File "/home/userName/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/celery/result.py", line 436, in state
return self._get_task_meta()['status']
File "/home/userName/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/celery/result.py", line 375, in _get_task_meta
return self._maybe_set_cache(self.backend.get_task_meta(self.id))
File "/home/userName/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/celery/backends/amqp.py", line 156, in get_task_meta
binding.declare()
File "/home/userName/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/kombu/entity.py", line 605, in declare
self._create_queue(nowait=nowait, channel=channel)
File "/home/userName/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/kombu/entity.py", line 614, in _create_queue
self.queue_declare(nowait=nowait, passive=False, channel=channel)
File "/home/userName/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/kombu/entity.py", line 649, in queue_declare
nowait=nowait,
 File "/home/userName/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/amqp/channel.py", line 1147, in queue_declare
nowait, arguments),
File "/home/userName/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/amqp/abstract_channel.py", line 50, in send_method
conn.frame_writer(1, self.channel_id, sig, args, content)
File "/home/userName/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/amqp/method_framing.py", line 166, in write_frame
write(view[:offset])
File "/home/userName/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/amqp/transport.py", line 258, in write
self._write(s)
**ConnectionResetError: [Errno 104] Connection reset by peer**
```

I am using Python 3.5, Airflow 1.8, Celery 4.1.0, and RabbitMQ 3.5.7 as the worker :
It looks like I am having a problem on RabbitMQ, but I cannot figure out the reason.

Comment: Did you ever figure this out? having the same problem.

Comment: @trejas We did not solved this issue before. 
The proposed solution below. https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/AIRFLOW-342 might help. 
For us, we changed our broker to SQL instead of Rabbitmq

Answer (score 0):

The reported error seems to be a identified error [solved in Airflow 1.10.0](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/AIRFLOW-342).

Answer (score 0):

Had the same issue.

Your dag contains many API calls to a server and your airflow scheduler has a limit to follow, there isn't a specific number of request at once to abide by but you should do trial and error to find the number that works for your Airflow environment. usually occurs when your dag has n number of tasks to run alongside each other simultaneously.

this issue is not resolvable by any updates that claimed in answers, I was getting the error even when I was using the latest release.